# How to get the profile pic aligned center?

Tags: html, css

I can't get the profile pic to be centered. Any ideas on how to do that? I tried using the float to get the back button inline but it shifts the profile pic to the right slightly. How do I get it to align?

[image: Output in browser]

Here is my HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>About Me</title>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="blackbg.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" class="myButton">Back</a>
    <header>
        <img id="profilepic" src="http://i.imgur.com/rEVubAf.jpg">
        <h1>Zheng Yuxiang</h1>
    </header>
    <article>
        <p>I am a fuccboi that loves bad bitches. Oh and I love Yeezy too and his overpriced sneakers.</p>
        <img src="http://sneakerbardetroit.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/adidas-yeezy-350-boost-moonrock-release.jpg" alt="Yeezy 350" width=600px id="yeezy">
    </article>  

</body>
```

Here is my CSS code.

```
body {
  background-color: black;
}
header {
  text-align: center;
  color:white;
}
#profilepic {
  margin: 40px 0px 0px px;
  border: 4.5px solid white;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
h1 {
  font-family:avenir ,sans-serif;
  font-variant: light;
  font-size:50px;
}
nav {
  font-size: 15px;
}
a {
  margin:5px;
  color:white;
}
@media (max-width: 750px) {
h1 {
    font-size: 25px
}
nav {
    font-size: 10px;
}
}
article {
  text-align: center;
}
#yeezy {
  padding:20px;
}
p {
  color:#b7b1b5;
}
.myButton {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  background-color:#ededed;
  -moz-border-radius:42px;
  -webkit-border-radius:42px;
  border-radius:42px;
  display:inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
  color:#777777;
  font-family:avenir;
  font-size:17px;
  padding:14px 22px;
  text-decoration:none;
  float:left;
}
.myButton:hover {
  background-color:#dfdfdf;
}
.myButton:active {
  position:relative;
  top:1px;
}
```

Comment: at myButton{ } class just add this position: absolute; will solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the button is taking up some of the space on the line that the image is on, so the image container cannot have the full width. Move the button element *after* the header element and position it absolutely.

This solution allows the button to stay on the same line as the image, but allow the image to be centered.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
header {
  text-align: center;
  color:white;
}
#profilepic {
  margin: 40px 0px 0px px;
  border: 4.5px solid white;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
h1 {
  font-family:avenir ,sans-serif;
  font-variant: light;
  font-size:50px;
}
nav {
  font-size: 15px;
}
a {
  margin:5px;
  color:white;
}
@media (max-width: 750px) {
h1 {
    font-size: 25px
}
nav {
    font-size: 10px;
}
}
article {
  text-align: center;
}
#yeezy {
  padding:20px;
}
p {
  color:#b7b1b5;
}
.myButton {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  background-color:#ededed;
  -moz-border-radius:42px;
  -webkit-border-radius:42px;
  border-radius:42px;
  display:inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
  color:#777777;
  font-family:avenir;
  font-size:17px;
  padding:14px 22px;
  text-decoration:none;
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
}
.myButton:hover {
  background-color:#dfdfdf;
}
.myButton:active {
  position:relative;
  top:1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>About Me</title>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="blackbg.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <img id="profilepic" src="http://i.imgur.com/rEVubAf.jpg">
        <h1>Zheng Yuxiang</h1>
    </header>
    <a href="#" class="myButton">Back</a>
    <article>
        <p>I am a fuccboi that loves bad bitches. Oh and I love Yeezy too and his overpriced sneakers.</p>
        <img src="http://sneakerbardetroit.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/adidas-yeezy-350-boost-moonrock-release.jpg" alt="Yeezy 350" width=600px id="yeezy">
    </article>  

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
header {
  text-align: center;
  color:white;
  position: relative;
}
#profilepic {
  margin: 40px 0px 0px px;
  border: 4.5px solid white;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
h1 {
  font-family:avenir ,sans-serif;
  font-variant: light;
  font-size:50px;
}
nav {
  font-size: 15px;
}
a {
  margin:5px;
  color:white;
}
@media (max-width: 750px) {
h1 {
    font-size: 25px
}
nav {
    font-size: 10px;
}
}
article {
  text-align: center;
}
#yeezy {
  padding:20px;
}
p {
  color:#b7b1b5;
}
.myButton {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  background-color:#ededed;
  -moz-border-radius:42px;
  -webkit-border-radius:42px;
  border-radius:42px;
  display:inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
  color:#777777;
  font-family:avenir;
  font-size:17px;
  padding:14px 22px;
  text-decoration:none;
  float:left;
}
.myButton:hover {
  background-color:#dfdfdf;
}
.myButton:active {
  position:relative;
  top:1px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>About Me</title>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="blackbg.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    
    <header>
        <img id="profilepic" src="http://i.imgur.com/rEVubAf.jpg">
        <h1>Zheng Yuxiang</h1>
      
    <a href="#" class="myButton">Back</a>
    </header>
    <article>
        <p>I am a fuccboi that loves bad bitches. Oh and I love Yeezy too and his overpriced sneakers.</p>
        <img src="http://sneakerbardetroit.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/adidas-yeezy-350-boost-moonrock-release.jpg" alt="Yeezy 350" width=600px id="yeezy">
    </article>  

</body>
```

Comment: Beat me to it; this is how I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have use `float:left` in `<a>` on the top

use follwing css in header

```
header {
  text-align: center;
  color:white;
  clear:left;
}
```

This is the simplest way with a line of css added

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/voz0vnvL/

Answer (score 0):

just replace this:

```
        .myButton {
        margin-top: 40px;
        margin-left: 40px;
        background-color: #ededed;
        -moz-border-radius: 42px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 42px;
        border-radius: 42px;
        display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #777777;
        font-family: avenir;
        font-size: 17px;
        padding: 14px 22px;
        text-decoration: none;
        float: left;
    }
```

by this:

```
        .myButton {
        margin-top: 40px;
        margin-left: 40px;
        background-color: #ededed;
        -moz-border-radius: 42px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 42px;
        border-radius: 42px;
        display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #777777;
        font-family: avenir;
        font-size: 17px;
        padding: 14px 22px;
        text-decoration: none;
        float: absolute;
    }
```